# double while, new feature in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I found that this compiles in Microsoft Visual C++ 2010.

```
void main()
{
    int i=9;
    while (i>4)
    {
        i--; 
    }
    while (i>6);
}
```

Probably not.. the second while does not seems to have an effect

Comment: While the loops are fine, `void main()` is an error (or, I suppose, it could be called "non-portable Microsoft language extension"), try compiling your program using [a different compiler](https://ideone.com/XuFm2)

Comment: why do you expect it not to have compiled ?

Comment: What if the second loop had been while(i>3); ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is nothing unusual about it. It's two `while` statements, except the other one has an empty body. The bigger problem is `void main`.

Comment: I was first! `:b`

Comment: cannot see who is first, I cannot see seconds.

Comment: @Aftershock: Hover your mouse over the answer timestamp.

Comment: @Aftershock: That's why you can sort answers by age ("oldest").

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: A) How is he supposed to get the bonobo thing from my gorilla avatar? B) You already got my upvote for being second. C) Aftershock's nick is one of those where the comment-reply script fails and puts in the wrong nick ("Atershock"). D) Fortunately, the comment-threading script makes you discover that.

Answer (score 15):

Your

```
while (i>6);
```

does not have any effect. It's just a loop with an empty body:

```
while (i>6)
  ;
```

Answer (score 6):

You have two separate `while` loops here. The second just has an empty body. Reformat to:

```
int i=9;
while (i>4)
{
    i--; 
}

while (i>6)
    ;
```

...and it might make more sense. In this case, i is 4 upon entry to the second loop, so the second loop never executes.

Answer (score 2):

`while (i>6);` is no new feature, it simply says that while `i` is greater than `6` it should execute an empty statement `;`.